# Apache HttpClient return entity with length -1

Tags: entity, httpclient, response

I'm using the fundamental http request with the same URL. Sometimes it return an entity with length -1. While the response status is OK and the entity is not null.

I run the program for about 10 times, it can work 2 times randomly while the other attempts failed with "Content-type: text/html, lentgh: -1" .

Is there something else I need to set?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(textURL.toString());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(entity.getContentType() + ", length: " + entity.getContentLength());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i hit the same question too!i think the content length getting by the method may just get from the header!but sometimes there is no header of content length;if you
really want to get the length,you can consume the content yourself.then you can get the length;

```
public String toString()
{
    InputStream instream=null;
    try{
        instream = this.getContent();
         Charset charset = null;
         if (instream == null) {
                return null;
         }
         int i = (int)this.getContentLength();
         if (i < 0) {
               i = 4096;
         }
         final ContentType contentType = ContentType.get(this);
         if (contentType != null) {
                charset = contentType.getCharset();
         }
         if (charset == null) {
                charset = HTTP.DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET;
         }
         final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
         final CharArrayBuffer buffer = new CharArrayBuffer(i);
         final char[] tmp = new char[1024];
         int l;
         int length=0;
         while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
               buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
               length+=l;
         }
         setContentLength(length*2);
         return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            instream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```